# Python: Cumulative Sum on Multiple IDs with missing row

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a large dataset with 104 unique dates and 200k SKUs. For this explanation I am using 3 SKUs and 4 dates.

The data is as follows

```
 Date      SKU        Demand      Supply
 20160501   1            10          10
 20160508   1            35          20
 20160501   2            20          15
 20160508   2            15          20
 20160522   2            5           0
 20160522   3            55          45
```

The rows are populated only where there is a non-zero Demand or supply.
I want to calculate cumulative Demand and Supply, while having continuous Date range for all IDs by adding 0 in the missing date.

My output would be like this

```
Date       SKU        Demand      Supply    Cum_Demand    Cum_Supply
20160501     1         10         10         10            10
20160508     1         35         20         45            30
20160515     1         0          0          45            30
20160522     1         0          0          45            30
20160501     2         20         15         20            15
20160508     2         15         20         35            35
20160515     2         0          0          35            35
20160522     2         5          0          40            35
20160501     3         0          0          0             0
20160508     3         0          0          0             0
20160515     3         0          0          0             0
20160522     3         55         45         55            45
```

Code for the dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[20160501,20160508,20160501,20160508,20160522,20160522],
                 'SKU':[1,1,2,2,2,3],
                 'Demand':[10,35,20,15,5,55],
                 'Supply':[10,20,15,20,0,45]}
                ,columns=['Date', 'SKU', 'Demand', 'Supply'])
```

Comment: How do I go about adding 0's where there is missing date for any ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to first `reindex`, then `groupby` + `cumsum` and can `concatenate` back:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[20160501,20160508,20160515,20160522], 
                                  data.SKU.unique()], names=['Date', 'SKU'])
#If have all unique dates needed in column then: 
#pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.unique(data.Date), data.SKU.unique()])

data2 = data.set_index(['Date', 'SKU']).reindex(idx).fillna(0)
data2 = pd.concat([data2, data2.groupby(level=1).cumsum().add_prefix('Cum_')], 1).sort_index(level=1).reset_index()
```

#### Output `data2`:

```
        Date  SKU  Demand  Supply  Cum_Demand  Cum_Supply
0   20160501    1    10.0    10.0        10.0        10.0
1   20160508    1    35.0    20.0        45.0        30.0
2   20160515    1     0.0     0.0        45.0        30.0
3   20160522    1     0.0     0.0        45.0        30.0
4   20160501    2    20.0    15.0        20.0        15.0
5   20160508    2    15.0    20.0        35.0        35.0
6   20160515    2     0.0     0.0        35.0        35.0
7   20160522    2     5.0     0.0        40.0        35.0
8   20160501    3     0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0
9   20160508    3     0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0
10  20160515    3     0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0
11  20160522    3    55.0    45.0        55.0        45.0
```

You will need to be careful about your dates. In this case I explicitly listed the order so earlier dates appeared first. If they are numbers, then you can use `np.unique` which **will** sort the values, ensuring dates are ordered. But this relies upon every date appearing in your `DataFrame` at least once. Otherwise you will need to create your list of ordered dates somehow.

Comment: The Week and Ids are as multi-index. How do I get them into columns and rename them?

Comment: @NeilS See my update. You can add `names` when you create your `MultiIndex` and then just `.reset_index` after the concat to make them into columns.

Answer (score 1):

Start by converting the `date` to `datetime` format:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y%m%d')
```

You can create a weekly [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) using the existing dates:

```
ix = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max() + pd.DateOffset(1), freq="W")
```

The following step would be to `GorupBy` `SKU`, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) according to the created date range, and choose a filling method according to the column, `ffill` and `bfill` to fill all `NaNs` in the case of `SKU` and `0` for the `Demand` and `Supply`.

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Date').groupby('SKU').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(ix)[['SKU']])
                          .ffill().bfill().reset_index(0, drop=True))
df2 = (df.set_index('Date').groupby('SKU').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(ix)[['Demand','Supply']])
                          .fillna(0).reset_index(0, drop=True))
```

The final step is to concatenate the two dataframes, and take the`cumsum` of `Demand` and `Supply`:

```
df_final = pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1)

(df_final.assign(**df_final.groupby('SKU')
    .agg({'Demand':'cumsum','Supply':'cumsum'})
    .add_prefix('cum_')))

            SKU   Demand  Supply    cum_Demand  cum_Supply
2016-05-01  1.0    10.0    10.0        10.0        10.0
2016-05-08  1.0    35.0    20.0        45.0        30.0
2016-05-15  1.0     0.0     0.0        45.0        30.0
2016-05-22  1.0     0.0     0.0        45.0        30.0
2016-05-01  2.0    20.0    15.0        20.0        15.0
2016-05-08  2.0    15.0    20.0        35.0        35.0
2016-05-15  2.0     0.0     0.0        35.0        35.0
2016-05-22  2.0     5.0     0.0        40.0        35.0
2016-05-01  3.0     0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0
2016-05-08  3.0     0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0
2016-05-15  3.0     0.0     0.0         0.0         0.0
2016-05-22  3.0    55.0    45.0        55.0        45.0
```

Comment: Let me know if this helped @NeilS

Comment: This did help. And this will also group by the rows to get the sum on a weekly level for the SKU right?

Comment: I guess not. It will have multiple indexes